# How to fix this error in NodeJS - 'Error: read ECONNRESET'?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to make a Login and Registration API using NodeJS, Express and MongoDB, and I am using *bcryptjs* for hashing password. But when I try to login, I face an error in Postman saying *Error: read ECONNRESET*. The user.js route file code looks something like this:

```
const router = require('express').Router();
let user = require('../models/user.model');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

// register route!
router.route('/register').post((req,res) => {
    const name = req.body.name;
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;

    let errors = [];

    if(!name || !email || !password) {
        errors.push({ msg: 'Please fill all the details!' });
    }

    // check password length
    if(password.length < 6) {
        errors.push({ msg: 'Password should be atleast 6 characters long!' });
    }

    if(errors.length > 0 ){
        res.status(400).json('Error: ' + errors)
    } else {
        const newUser = new user({
            name,
            email,
            password  
        })

        bcrypt.hash(password, 10, (err, hash) => {
            if(err) throw err;
            // set password to hash
            newUser.password = hash
            // save user
            newUser.save()
            .then(() => {
                res.json('User has registered successfully!');
            })
            .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
        })
    }
})

// login router
router.route('/login').post((req,res) => {
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;

    let errors = [];

    // match user
    user.findOne({ email: email })
    .then(user => {
        if(!user) {
            errors.push({ msg: 'Username is not registered!' });
        }

        hash = user.password

        bcrypt.compare(password, hash,(err,res) => {
            if(res) {
                res.json('User logged in!');
            } else {
                res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err)
            }
        })
    })
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));

    if(errors.length > 0) {
        res.json(errors);
    }
})

module.exports = router;
```

And the code for the Schema looks like this :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minLength: 6
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minLength: 6
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
})


const user = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = user;
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Your app is listening on some port?

Comment: @HamzaAnis Yes I am listening the app at port 5000.

Comment: Use console.log(err) inside the bcrypt compare and share the result ?